# Java: String from scanner.next() and .equals() comparison failure

Tags: java, string, input, comparison, java.util.scanner

I have an input read from scanner, which I am then comparing to a hard coded string variable

```
String MOVE = input.next();  // I type in "MOVE N"
MOVE = MOVE.trim();
System.out.print(MOVE.equals("MOVE N"));
```

This returned false. I added trim()

```
String MOVE = input.next(); // I type in "MOVE N"
System.out.print(MOVE.equals("MOVE N"));
```

Still false.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is output of `System.out.println ("'" + MOVE + "'")`?

Comment: did you debug your code?

Answer (score 11):

You probably want `nextLine()`. The `next()` method will just return the next *token*, which by default will be the next word (i.e. it breaks at space).

Next time, you should add a call to `System.out.println(MOVE);` to help you diagnose this - that way you could see that the result is just `"MOVE"` instead of `"MOVE N"`. (And then you'd consult the docs for [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)...)

Additionally, I strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions for your variables - so `move` instead of `MOVE` for example.

Comment: Scanner Questions have become a regular to the party

Comment: thanks, nextLine() works. don't worry about the naming conventions, I do follow them, this was oversimplified for the sake of example

Comment: @njl: Why would you follow naming conventions for your real code but then violate them for sample code? You're trying to communicate with many other developers: following conventions helps make that communication smoother.

Answer (score 0):

```
String MOVE = input.nextLine ();  // I type in "MOVE N"
MOVE = MOVE.trim ();
System.out.print (MOVE.equals ("MOVE N"));
```